Custom Types Not Being Recognized
I have this Expressjs project that was originally written in JS and now we're working on slowly converting it to TS. The folder structure looks something like this:
- server
  - controllers
  - middleware
  - models
  - routes
  - types
    - express.d.ts
  - app.js - entry point
- node_modules
- package.json
- package-lock.json
- tsconfig.json

Then when running npm run dev aka nodemon --exec ts-node server/app.js, I get this error: TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript: where I'm trying to access req.user
I have my custom definition for the request object that includes user in express.d.ts:
// types/express.d.ts
import * as express from 'express';

declare global {
    namespace Express {
        interface Request {
            user?: { // Define the shape of the user object
                sub: string; // The subject of the user
                role: string; // The role of the user
            };
        }
    }
}

I also have my tsconfig.json file:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",                              // Specify ECMAScript target version
    "module": "commonjs",                        // Specify module code generation
    "strict": true,                              // Enable all strict type-checking options
    "esModuleInterop": true,                     // Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,                        // Skip type checking of all declaration files
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,   // Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file
    "outDir": "./dist",                          // Redirect output structure to the dist folder
    "rootDir": "./server",                        // Specify the root directory of input files
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "server/types", "./server/types", "./types"],
  },
  "include": [
      "server"
  ],               
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]                    // Exclude node_modules and dist directories
}

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I can't get it to recognize the custom type. Probably an easy stupid thing, but any ideas?
Also, running tsc does not cause any errors, which makes no sense to me.


Is there a reason you're trying to set global types like that on the express library instead of just defining your own interface that extends Request? 2. Can you share the error message and the code that is throwing it? The prefix to the error message isn't enough.

